Identifying the type of the given random variable
$\begin{equation*}
F(x)=
     \begin{cases}
         0   &x < 0\\
         \frac{x}{2} &0 \leq x < 1 \\
         1-\frac{1}{(2x)^2}  &x \geq1 \\
     \end{cases}
\end{equation*}$
Given a random variable $X$ with the distribution above, I classified this random variable as continuous as $Im(X)=[0,+\infty[$, what would be the case of a mixed random variable? If, for example, the function $F$ was defined as a step function for a certain interval and the other part had a similar graph as the one for $x\geq 0$?

It has a jump of magnitude $\frac 3  4-\frac 1  2=\frac  14$ at $1$ so $P(X=1)=\frac   1 4$.

It is a mixed random variable (neither continuous nor discrete).

@Amir It is indeed a continuous random variable. The domain of values is given over a continuous set from negative infinity to positive infinity. This is an example of what a mixed random variable would look like $G(x)=1/6$
for $x=−3,−2,−1$
and $G(x)=1/2x^2$
for $x>1$

@Alborz A continuous random variable has a continuous cdf. Note that there is a jump at point $1$. It is mixed becuase for some points $x$ in the support $\mathbb P(X=x)>0$, whose probabilities sum to $a<1$, and for the other points $x$ in the support $\mathbb P(X=x)=0$.
